# Trouble with WP child theme

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wonder how if I have already changed the content of my wordpress site theme how can I create child theme from it so I don't need create the entire site from the begining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using below plugin. you can create child theme.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/

Comment: Thanks @ShitalMarakana but does it work if I already changed parent theme?

Comment: Yes, It is working. because you can make child theme of parent theme.

Comment: The thing that happens to me is that i changed parent theme so when i create child theme it is set original theme (parent theme without my changes) so how can I replace those two? @Shital

Comment: just copy your parent theme file by using plugin and you can edit your child theme file. like you can add new function in function.php child theme file. more information in plugin screen shot and description.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link for child theme https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes You need to create files inside your child theme directory(theme-child) style.css & functions.php